# Ruby - Hash to methods recursively

Tags: ruby

I have a hash-of-hashes and I need to turn it into methods where they key is the method name, and the value is what the method returns, but with the extra requirement that if a value is a also a hash, the whole value is returned.

For instance:

```
hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => { :a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3} }
hash.c.a  #=> 1
hash.c    #=> { :a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
```

How would I be able to do this?  Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) to make a data structure like that.  For example:

```
require 'ostruct'
s = OpenStruct.new(a: 1, b: 2, c: OpenStruct.new(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3))
s.c.a # => 1
s.c   # => #<OpenStruct a=1, b=2, c=3>
```

Comment: What if I had a hash which is 100+ levels deep, how could I iterate over the hash?

Comment: That is a different question. You could post another question, but you would need to make sure that what you are asking is clear. Here, for example, you are interested in retrieving the value of `:a` in the hash `hash.c`, but not the value of `:a`, in the hash `hash`. (You obviously cannot have two methods with the same name in a class.) It is not at all clear how that would extend to nested hashes when the same key appears multiple times in the nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie). Hashie is a set of hash-like extensions. Among those are hashes that you can access directly like fields - see specifically the [Mash](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#mash) option:

mash = Hashie::Mash.new(:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => Hashie::Mash.new(:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3))

Comment: A note that Hashie:::Mash.new should automatically recursively alter nested hashes. So you shouldn't need to explicitly say :c=> Hash::Mash.new(...) etc. You should just be able to pass in the whole hash with its nested hashes / array and Hashie figures it out.

Answer (score 0):

As your receiver is a hash, you must define the methods on the class `Hash`:

```
def makem(h)
  h.each do |k,v|
    case v
    when Hash
      Hash.instance_eval { define_method(k.to_s) { v } }
      v.each { |kk,vv| Hash.instance_eval { define_method(kk.to_s) { vv } } }
    end
  end
end
```

Let's try it:

```
h = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => { :a => 1, :b => 2, :d => 3 } }

makem(h)
Hash.instance_methods(false).select { |m| m.size == 1 }
  #=> [:c, :a, :b, :d] 
h.c
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :d=>3} 
h.c.a
  #=> 1 
h.c.b
  #=> 2 
h.c.d
  #=> 3
```

In your example, you have:

```
:c => { :a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
```

If you want a method `c` that returns the above hash, you obviously cannot define another method of the same name that would return `3`.

You may wish to reconsider the advisability of defining these methods. Perhaps it would be more useful to construct methods such as `def m(hash, key)` within your class.